# CSS transform cause the position to become 'relative'

Tags: html, css

It seems like CSS transform interferes with relative positioning, as illustrated in the demo. How to make the transformed element not relative?

[demo](https://codepen.io/ioowilly/pen/wMbyaz)

```
<div class="relative container">
  This is a relatively positioned container
  <div class="absolute child">
    This is an absolutely positioned element
  </div>
</div>
<div class="translate container">
  This is a transformed container
  <div class="absolute child">
    This is an absolutely positioned element, still positioned relative to the transformed container
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve. Both looks similar to me.

Comment: Transform creates a positioning context just like position: relative; this is by design.

Comment: the first duplicate is a generic one that deals with all the properties that do the same (including transform)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that a result of the transform is to just give the element a position: relative.

Rather:

> For elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model, any value other than none for the transform property also causes the element to establish a containing block for all descendants. Its padding box will be used to layout for all of its absolute-position descendants, fixed-position descendants, and descendant fixed background attachments.

See the spec at: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering

So, in your example the transform applied to the parent sets a new coordinate system and gives the absolutely positioned element its containing block.

If the transform is set to none then CSS will search back for the next ancestor which sets a containing block (if there isn't one it gets back to the root) to find the containing block for the absolutely positioned element.